# Youtube api autoplay:1 does not fire onStateChange event for upcoming live videos

Tags: youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

The youtube iframe api player behaves differently for upcoming live videos that are embedded when using the autoplay feature.

Setting the `autoplay: 1` does not fire the **onStateChange** event for **upcoming live** videos that are embedded using the iframe api.

`autoplay NOT set` **onStateChange** event fires when video is loaded 
https://jsbin.com/luqacar/edit?html,output

`autoplay: 1` **onStateChange** does not fire when video is loaded 
https://jsbin.com/mobuwew/edit?html,output